# changing the encoding for eclipse

Tags: eclipse, utf-8

I want to change the encoding for eclipse to UTF-8

Answer (score 6):

Go to Window > Preference > General > Workspace and on the "Text file encoding" panel select UTF-8

Comment: Note that you can also set this per project in the project properties.

Answer (score 2):

using Eclipse 3.* (I think it didn't change since 3.0)

Click on menu "Window/preferences"

Select General/Workspace.

it will show you a panel containing a sub-panel titled "T[ext file encoding"](http://wiki.openbravo.com/wiki/images/0/04/Preferencesunix.jpg), letting you choose either default platform one or a specific one.